# Glide not able to load some of images failed with exception

Tags: android, android-glide, android-image

I have issue with image loading. Only some of the images are not loading. I have tried using glide and image loader.

**Glide code :**

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.getImage4x3().trim()+"?w=430&h=275")
                .into(holder.mBinding.ivPromotion);
```

**Glide dependency :**

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

I have also tried : 3.9.0 , 4.0.0 , 3.6.1 , 3.8.0

**Error :**

```
load failed for http://mcms-uat.mercatus.com.sg/en/-/media/E3BE24B58E1144228C62D2364F4FF543.ashx?rev=50ebbcc572e6488c826a23276ab9bf08 with size [320x240]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 4 causes:
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
    java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, http://mcms-uat.mercatus.com.sg/en/-/media/E3BE24B58E1144228C62D2364F4FF543.ashx?rev=50ebbcc572e6488c826a23276ab9bf08
        Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
        Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->Drawable}
        Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
```

**Image :**

http://mcms-uat.mercatus.com.sg/en/-/media/E3BE24B58E1144228C62D2364F4FF543.ashx?rev=50ebbcc572e6488c826a23276ab9bf08

Please check!

Comment: It appears you have Glide annotation processor missing. Read their implementation again: [Glide Github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permission in your manifest?

Comment: Seems your code is correct. problem is with your image. download that image form url and check their dimension. it is 5120x3840 and you are tying to set inside 320x240 size. edit/crop that remote image and check it again.

Comment: @sonhvp Yes i am calling apis also

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Still same issue

Comment: @Annie model.getImage4x3() is returning what can you paste here?

Comment: @PratikDasa Please check :  "image4x3": "http://mcms-uat.mercatus.com.sg/en/-/media/E3BE24B58E1144228C62D2364F4FF543.ashx?rev=50ebbcc572e6488c826a23276ab9bf08",

Comment: which android device are you using? which API level?

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA Android 7 motorolla device

Comment: Show your project level Gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all of you for your Answers and suggestions. I have resolved the issue. There was problem in my URL parameter it was `?w=430&h=275` instead of `&w=430&h=275`. Due to this image was not cropped and issue in loading big image, so i resolved it by changing parameters

Answer (score 3):

```
1) Add below dependencies into app/build.gradle      
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:your_glide_version'
```

2) put android:largeHeap="true" into  tag of  manifest file

3) and use like below

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    Glide.with(context)  // this
       .load(imagePath)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
       .into(imageView);
```

Comment: what's the reason behind using `android:largeHeap="true"`? Large heap is not a solution to this problem and even in case of OOM problem, largeHeap is still not the solution. If an app can not work in the provided heap size, it clearly needs some attention.

Answer (score 3):

Simply Use This Method and You're Done. And if it's not worked, then go        with Picasso Library, Because this issue is already STALED by Glide Itself.

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("Your Network Image Path")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        iv.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        iv.buildDrawingCache();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) { }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with loading large images in glide

Either use Picasso library

> implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

or you can use facebook library also, available on their website (this will also load gif images well).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try by changing context Like applicationcontext,or base context

Answer (score 0):

it may because the HTTP is default is disallowed since Andoird 9. You can add the following at the AndroidMainfest.xml.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```